# WordPress schedule a task to update plugin option

Tags: wordpress, task, hook, schedule

I'm working on a plugin for wordpress where I need to update a database option using the single event scheduler, but it doesn't seem to fire.
My code:

```
function task_to_perform()
{
    update_option( "number_of_cubes", 50);
    wp_unschedule_event('lalala_hook');
}

add_action( 'lalala_hook','task_to_perform' );

function some_other_function()
{
    if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'lalala_hook' ) )
        wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 10, 'lalala_hook' );
}
```

So when I call `some_other_function();` I want wordpress to set a schedule time for 10 seconds from now to update the option "number_of_cubes".

This option is defined in the plugin like this:

```
register_setting("stars_settings", "number_of_cubes");

if (!get_option( "number_of_cubes"))
    update_option( "number_of_cubes", 0);
```

Comment: use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/task-scheduler/

Comment: @ChandraKumar what i'm trying to do is part of plugin, and so I want it to be independant of any other plugins